# How can I solve this differental equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How can I solve this differental equation:

\begin{align} \left(\frac{1}{x}-y^2\frac{1}{\left(x-y\right)^2}\right)dx&+\left(x^2\frac{1}{\left(x-y\right)^2}-\frac{1}{y}\right)dy=0\quad?\\ \end{align}
I have this as a part of my homework, and there were like 20 other differential equations that I easily solved, but this one stood out.

This is not linear, not separable. I don't know how to approach this problem. If you could tell me to what class this kind of equation belongs, and some methods to solve them, I would be very very glad.

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't solved it but have you checked if it is an exact differential equation(DE)? Also, if it is a homogeneous DE?

Comment: @psitama when I check if it's an exact  DE or not I get that dM/dy=! dN/dx.

Comment: $M dx +N dy=0$ compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial y }M = \frac {\partial}{\partial x }N$ exact differential equation.

Comment: @S.G but I get that they're not equal to each other.

Comment: @Britanica, recheck your calculations. This is an exact DE.

Comment: Note that $M(x,y)=-N(y,x)$ so it is an exact DE.

Comment: If you follow this tutorial https://math24.net/exact-differential-equations.html you'll find $\ln(x)-\ln(y)+\frac{xy}{x-y}=C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation can be rewritten as $$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}-\frac{y^2}{(x-y)^2}\mathrm{d}x+\frac{x^2}{(x-y)^2}\mathrm{d}y-\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}=0.$$ Here, I would suggest the substitution $xw=y.$ Hence $$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}-\frac{w^2}{(1-w)^2}\mathrm{d}x+\frac1{(1-w)^2}\mathrm{d}(xw)-\frac{\mathrm{d}(xw)}{xw}=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}-\frac{w^2}{(1-w)^2}\mathrm{d}x+\frac{x}{(1-w)^2}\mathrm{d}w+\frac{w}{(1-w)^2}\mathrm{d}x-\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{w}-\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}=-\frac{w^2}{(1-w)^2}\mathrm{d}x+\frac{w}{(1-w)^2}\mathrm{d}x+\frac{x}{(1-w)^2}\mathrm{d}w-\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{w}=\frac{w(1-w)}{(1-w)^2}\mathrm{d}x+x\mathrm{d}\left(\frac1{1-w}\right)-\mathrm{d}[\ln(w)]=\frac{w}{1-w}\mathrm{d}x+x\mathrm{d}\left(\frac1{1-w}\right)-\mathrm{d}[\ln(w)]=-\mathrm{d}x+\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1-w}+x\mathrm{d}\left(\frac1{1-w}\right)-\mathrm{d}[\ln(w)]=\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{x}{1-w}\right)-\mathrm{d}x-\mathrm{d}[\ln(w)]=\mathrm{d}\left[\frac{x}{1-w}-x-\ln(w)\right]=\mathrm{d}\left[\frac{x-(x-xw)}{1-w}-\ln(w)\right]=\mathrm{d}\left[\frac{xw}{1-w}-\ln(w)\right]=\mathrm{d}\left[\frac{x^2w}{x-xw}-\ln(w)\right]=\mathrm{d}\left[\frac{xy}{x-y}-\ln(y)+\ln(x)\right]=0.$$